# How to make options (public or private) on Post? reactjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I'm creating Social Network app using MERN. One of the thing what I have made so far is that user can create post and I have also followers and followings. My new task is to make option on post so it can be public or private. I don't know how to do that. Has anybody idea or example of code how to do it? Thanks!

This is my post model:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    registration_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            text: String,
            userID: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

This is my user model:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    registration_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    profile_image: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    user_bio: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    followers: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user"
    }],
    following: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "user"
    }]
})
```

and here is the logic how of creating post:

```
router.post('/', auth, (req, res) => {

    const newPost = new Post({
        userID: req.user._id,
        content: req.body.content
    })

    newPost
        .save()
        .then(post => {
            res.json(post)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

And on front-end I have made dropdown menu with options 'Public' and 'Private'

EDIT
here is route where I get all posts:

```
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    Post
        .find()
        .populate('userID', 'first_name last_name profile_image _id')
        .sort({ registration_date: -1 })
        .then(post => res.json(post))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve these problems in several ways, you can add a field in the Post Model called "visibility" of type ENUM, which for now can accept "public" or "private", but in the future it can be implemented "protected" for example, to allow only followers to see the Posts. The default value for Post visibility can be "public":

Ok, how add this field can solve this problem? You can send a validation to mongo db in this way:

```js
const posts = await post.find({ userID: "123456", visibility: "public" });

// posts are filled with all posts of a user that visilibity are "public", so, all posts that the user maked as "private" not will be fetched
```

```js
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    userID: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    registration_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user"
        }
    ],
    // ==================
    // Add this field:
    // ==================
    visibility: {
        type: String,
        enum : ["public", "private"],
        default: "public"
    },
    comments: [
        {
            text: String,
            userID: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'user'
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Note: you probably will have problems with this current database system, because the "Comments" should be a new Model, with mainly three field: userId (id of user that comment); postId (post target id); and text (The comment text), why? in this way, you can do pagination with mongoose, and not necessary to fetch all comments in only one request (If you Post have 500 comments, 900?)